# Showing a string without a substring

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I got a little "problem". I have these two strings (one showing the message, and the other showing the index where "##Documents##" start):

```
        string text = currentNode.Properties["menuEntry"].Value;
        string index = text.IndexOf("##Documents##").ToString();
```

I want to have another string for the message WITHOUT "##Documents##". Any solution to continue from the code up above, or any other solution?

For example: Message: blablabla ##Documents## 123

And what I want to show: blablabla 123

Thanks and sorry for the noobish question.

Comment: Why not simply `message=message.Replace("##Documents##","")` ?

Comment: BTW: Why did you want to serialize the index as string? An index is usually only useful as a number.

Comment: @Georg: yea sorry, I've realised too late it was put as a string...

Comment: @TimSchmelter: yea i'm new here :D, don't know how all this works. Wanted to thank and accept all the answers ....

Comment: @CosminGabriel Click on the 'v' sign next to the answer you'll accept as an answer

Comment: @CosminGabriel: once you have enough reputation(15) you can upvote all answers that were helpful. Meanwhile you can accept the best answer by clicking the green check mark besides it. Read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Ric.Net: done, thank you all very much for helping, and really really sorry again for being noob-ish here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `Replace()` method like this:

```
string text = currentNode.Properties["menuEntry"].Value;
string message= text.Replace("##Documents##",string.Empty);
```

Comment: @CosminGabriel If you consider the question answered, consider marking it as answered to let other users know 'it's been handled'

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the substrings that occur before and after that substring if it is found.

```
int index = text.IndexOf("##Documents##");
string newText = text;
if(index > -1)
    newText = text.SubString(0, index) + text.SubString(index +13);
```